# When i can find Yii::app()->user->checkAccess

Tags: yii

I am new in Yii. And some things in this framework i am understand well. But i am can't understand how work `Yii::app()` and where i can find `Yii::app()->user->checkAccess` method?
Should you are explain me it. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried [searching](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=Yii++app+user+check+user&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) [for it](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=yii+app+user+check+access&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yii::app()->user is the user component, which is defined in your config file (usually /protected/config/main.php). In the components array you will find a 'user' component. The default class for this is CWebUser, so probably 'checkAccess' is defined in CWebUser (did not check this though).

You can write your own class extending CWebUser if you want to override this property (it's not a method).

Answer (score 0):

See your /protected/config/main.php file, and then you may find authManager section in components. In my case, I set the class of authManager to CDbAuthManager. In that class, checkAccess method is defined.